# Why does in-line Label Edit in Windows Explorer have a delay?

Tags: gui-design, windows-os

When you open Windows Explorer, then select some file or folder, then click its file name, an inline label-edit will be invoked. But there is an intentional delay before the textbox is displayed. Why?

First I thought its because I can move the mouse away until the textbox appears to cancel the edit, but it happens in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that the delay is to distinguish clicks from double clicks.

Comment: This is correct. If you use Control Panel to alter the double-click speed (under "Mouse" properties) then the speed of the textbox appearing changes accordingly.

Comment: For more detail, see Raymond Chen's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/11/10/9056610.aspx) on the topic.